# I wrote this and my teacher says that there's a problem with "exit" but I can't see why

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is the code and as I said he says that there's a problem with exit.

```
DECLARE
    a number:=1;
    b number:=6;
    exit BOOLEAN;
    BEGIN
        exit:='FALSE'; 
        WHILE NOT exit LOOP
            IF a>=b THEN
                exit:='TRUE';
            ELSE
                a:=(a+1);
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Along with the fact (as pointed out in @trincot's answer) that `EXIT` is a statement, you also can't assign a string value (`'FALSE'` or `'TRUE'`) to a variable of type `BOOLEAN`. The values which can be assigned to a boolean are `FALSE` and `TRUE` (without the single-quotes). Best of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exit` is a statement, and so you should not use it as a variable -- it is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/reservewords.htm). Just the statement on its own will exit the loop:

```
 DECLARE
    a number:=1;
    b number:=6;
 BEGIN
    LOOP
        IF a>=b THEN
            EXIT;
        ELSE
            a:=a+1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
 END;
```

You can also combine `EXIT` with a `WHEN` clause:

```
 DECLARE
    a number:=1;
    b number:=6;
 BEGIN
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN a>=b;
        a:=a+1;
    END LOOP;
 END;
```

Or you can add the inverse condition as a `WHILE` clause to the `LOOP` construct:

```
 DECLARE
    a number:=1;
    b number:=6;
 BEGIN
    WHILE a < b LOOP
        a:=a+1;
    END LOOP;
 END;
```